# ASP.NET CORE 2 + ANGULAR 4: NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: asp.net, angular, web, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use ngx-chips for tag-input, but I am having this issue with importing BrowserAnimationsModule.

On importing BrowserAnimationsModule, I get the error below:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Once I comment BrowserAnimationsModule in import under app.module.shared.ts, my app works normal but once I uncomment it, I come up with the same error.

Please how can I trash this, I have been working on this for more than 4days.
Or suggest any other angular 4 tag-input library
I am using ASP.NET Core 2 SPA Template.

Thanks...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your view's (Index.cshtml) app tag, replace the `asp-prerender-module` with `asp-ng2-prerender-module`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me with ASP.NET Core 2 and SPA template.

Comment: Is the asp-ng2-prerender-module a new keyword or your "solution" simply disable SSR?

Comment: If your components (Kendo UI in my case) are looking for 'window', then they are not compatible with SSR.  No 'window' or any other DOM elements on the server, right?  My 'solution' therefore was to get past this stumbling block and move on . . . to the next stumbling block.